# Pagination with AngularJS ng-table

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, pagination

**This is my index.js file where I defined my angular app**
**I am trying to implement client side pagination in AngularJS. I got the output properly using ui-bootstrap. Please help me implement it using ng-table**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngTable"])
app.controller("myCntrl", function ($scope, $http) {

$scope.getAllData = function () {
    $http({
        method: "get",
        url: "https://localhost:44370/Home/GetData",
    }).then(function (response) {
        $scope.employees = response.data;

    },
    )
}

$scope.employeesTable = new ngTableParams({
    page: 1,
    count: 5
}, {
    total: $scope.employees.length,
    getData: function ($defer, params) {
        $scope.data = $scope.employees.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
        $defer.resolve($scope.data);
    }

});
});
```

**This is my index.cshtml file. Please let me know where I went wrong**

```
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/esvit/ng-table/master/dist/ng-table.min.css">
<script src="https://rawgit.com/esvit/ng-table/master/dist/ng-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Index.js"></script>

<h2>Data</h2>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCntrl">
      <table ng-table="employeeTable" cellpadding="12" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
          <tr class="table-primary">
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Age</th>
              <th>Address</th>
              <th>Email Id</th>
              <th>Created On</th>
              <th>Modified On</th>
              <th>Created By</th>
              <th>Modified By</th>
          </tr>
          <tr ng-repeat="Emp in employees">
              <td>{{Emp.Id}}</td>
              <td>{{Emp.Name}}</td>
              <td>{{Emp.Age}}</td>
              <td>{{Emp.Address}}</td>
              <td>{{Emp.EmailId}}</td>
              <td>{{Emp.CreatedOn}}</td>
              <td>{{Emp.ModifiedOn}}</td>
              <td>{{Emp.CreatedBy}}</td>
              <td>{{Emp.ModifiedBy}}</td>
          </tr>
      </table>
  </div>
</div>
```